# Pandas Apply Function Working Very Slowly

Tags: pandas, lambda, nltk, apply, cython

I'm passing the following function to a pandas column with 3 million comments in order to extract the adjectives. I was expecting it to be done very quickly as it can be done in parallel computation. Though it's taking around 5 hours or so as if it is a for loop. Is there possible any solution to this? Like Cython?

```
 def get_adjectives(row):
    clean_row=''
    if type(row)==str:
      for word in row.split():
        if nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in ['JJ','JJR','JJS']:
          clean_row=clean_row+word+' '
    return clean_row

  df['adjectives'] = df[text_column].apply(get_adjectives)
```

Comment: Adding n strings the way you do is O(n*n). Put them into a list first and join at the very end => O(n). No need for cython.

Comment: That `apply` has to run `get_adjectives` once per row, that is 3 million times.

Answer (score 1):

Building on comment of @ead. Try this:

```py
def get_adjectives(row):
    clean_row = [] # list, not str
    if type(row)==str:
      for word in row.split():
        if nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in ['JJ','JJR','JJS']:
          clean_row.append(word) # Appending to list
    
    clean_row = ' '.join(clean_row) # joining all words in list, separated by space
    return clean_row

df['adjectives'] = df[text_column].apply(get_adjectives)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a quick fix, but if you import swifter it can look for a vectorized solution for you:

```
 def get_adjectives(row):
    clean_row = ''
    if type(row) == str:
      for word in row.split():
        if nltk.pos_tag([word])[0][1] in ['JJ','JJR','JJS']:
          clean_row = clean_row + word + ' '
    return clean_row

 import swifter
 df['adjectives'] = df[text_column].swifter.apply(get_adjectives)
```